# Run xcode ios project on Android

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, xcode, porting

I have made an ios app in Xcode 6.1.1 using objective-c.
What I want to do is port it to Android.
When I look at the internet I founded Marmalade and apportable.

As far as I can find the only way to use apportable is to contact them and let them do it. I sended a e-mail to apportable and asked what that is gonna cost me and (I hope you are sitting right now) there start price is at 70.000 bucks.

So the other option is apportable. When I look at there site it is mainly meant for games, but will it work with normal apps too? What can I expect from the program? Are there better solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used any system to migrate apps between platforms. I code them natively if needed, adjusting UI/UX as expected between platforms.

Having said this, for what I've heard in a conference where some guys from Apportable explained. They are slowly building up their system. But, as you can imagine, it's not that easy. On the other hand, it's straightforward to migrate from OpenGL to OpenGL, doesn't matter the platform. And that's the reason why games are widely supported, not only by Apportable but for many other cross-platforms.

If you ask me, my option would be to learn a bit of Android (once you know iOS, the basic knowledge of Android is peanuts), and code it. For simple apps, you can do it really fast.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. The problem right now is that the project in iOS is gettting kind of big. I think I would need quit some time to reproduce all those lines to Android, but many thanks anyway.

Comment: No problem. Some big companies develop a data layer on C++ in order to share that layer between platforms easily. That could've been another solution for you.

Comment: Please tell me, what company or options do I have? thanks in advanced!